# Detecting broken TCP connections after the system goes out of sleep

Tags: sockets, networking, linux-kernel

I'm maintaing an IRC client, which opens TCP connections to multiple servers. When the system goes into sleep for a few hours, the connection is often broken.

I could send application level IRC PING messages regularly, or even send TCP keepalive packets frequently (e.g. every 15 seconds, always), so that when the system goes out of sleep it tries sending a packet after a few seconds, then fails the conncetion after TCP RTO and I can open a proper conncetion again.

But my app could also be used on a mobile tethering hospot, so sending packets regularly would keep the phone radio in the fully awake state, decreasing the phone battery quickly.

I'd like to send just the packets that I need: ideally, just one packet when it's been too long since I last sent a packet.

I tried using TCP keepalive with a TCP_KEEPIDLE value of ~1 hour, so that whenever the system goes to sleep for 2 hours, it would immediately send a keepalive when going out of sleep.

But apparently, this did not work, as if time spent during sleep was not account for wrt the keepalive idle timeout.

How does keepalive relate to sleep? Is there a way to set my keepalive parameters so that a keepalive is only sent after a long period, and a long system sleep period counts?

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific question, but my solution for the TCP-vs-sleeping problem is to have a routine that runs just before the system goes to sleep, which closes any current TCP connections (since they almost certainly won't be viable later on anyway).  (this approach does require a way to get a callback just before the system goes to sleep, which I know how to do in Windows and MacOS but not for Linux)